# MongoDB data change delay in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would like to ask you about why my external instance MongoDB is slower than launched by Meteor.js.

I set the MONGO_URL environment variable to connect with my local database so the connection should be as fast as the database created by the Meteor.js.

However, when I tried to test publications with external database and I saw that I have one or two seconds latency, but when Meteor.js runs database all works properly (I saw the new data from database without delay).

Thanks for any help!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor has two ways to access changes in MongoDB:

- Pull: Meteor checks for updates at regular intervals. You may notice a few seconds delay.
- Push, also known as "oplog tailing": MongoDB sends data changes right when they are performed. Meteor registers it instantaneously.

You'll need to set the `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` environment variable to enable oplog tailing and have instantaneous updates. When Meteor starts up a local Mongo instance, is also sets up oplog tailing automatically.

Here's a detailed article about it: https://meteorhacks.com/mongodb-oplog-and-meteor/

Comment: The link to the article is dead.